# Styling the body in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to add styling to the body tag in Nuxt, but the default.vue seems to be overwriting it (it's not inheriting from body as it is in my pure html build - I'm porting it over to Nuxt).

I have this in the CSS:

```
body{font-family:'Geomanist', sans-serif;color:#000 !important}
```

However, when I run this, it keeps inheriting from "html" from the default.vue layout component (I don't include that in my build at all as you can see):

```
<script scoped>
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        script: [
          {
            src: '/js/vendor/jquery.min.js' 
          },
          {
            src: '/js/site.js' 
          }
        ]
        
      }
    }
    
    
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
@import '~/assets/css/style.min.css';
</style>
```

Looks like this in developer tools:

```
html {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

It should look like:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Geomanist', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

The default.vue looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
html {
  font-family:
    'Source Sans Pro',
    -apple-system,
    BlinkMacSystemFont,
    'Segoe UI',
    Roboto,
    'Helvetica Neue',
    Arial,
    sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.button--green {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #3b8070;
  color: #3b8070;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.button--green:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3b8070;
}
.button--grey {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #35495e;
  color: #35495e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.button--grey:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #35495e;
}
</style>
```

Comment: my guess is because you are scoping it, vue does not target the body nor html. its an element inside the body, the html targeted one works because its not scoped.

Comment: That was it!  Answer and receive your prize.  I only used scoped because I don't want this CSS to leak to other templates.  How do I prevent that?

Comment: To avoid that, you can either be more specific, target a specific class/id or re-write the value of some CSS properties down in the cascade aka in other layouts/components.

Answer (score 2):

In ***Nuxt 3*** you'll want to use this [(Reference)](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#body-tags):

```js
<script setup>
// pages/my-cool-page.vue or app.vue
useHead({
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: 'test'
  }
})
</script>
<template>
 <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</template>
<style>
.test {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Tip add css to body tag -->
    <body class="max-h-[100vh] max-w-[100vw] overflow-hidden"></body>
</div>
</template>
```

I recent aware when we create a second body tag and add classes to it, outermost body tag will has same classes. But we will have a redundant body tag.

Comment: In my case this answer just work on local not production

Comment: If you want to add classes to the body then you can do that by simply editing the `nuxt.config.js` adding `bodyAttrs: { class: 'max-h-[100vh] max-w-[100vw] overflow-hidden' }` inside `head: { ... }` object.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is because you are scoping it, vue does not target the body nor html. its an element inside the body, the html targeted one works because its not scoped.

If you dont want it to leak, Have a main global css file and the rest scoped.

put the global styles in `default.vue`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this in Nuxt3:
[page/index.vue, layouts/default.vue, scsss and nuxt.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lZ66.png)